# SqlDataSource insert error - too many arguments

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I want to insert a row into an Infragistics grid.  It has 2 columns, ID and Name. Both are bound.  But when I insert I only want to use the Name column as a parameter.  But when I use both, the insertion works. I have the ID as a parameter but I don't use it because it is an identity column. When i only use 'Name', I get the error, too many arguments for the stored procedure.

This is the markup:

```
<ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid runat="server" height="600px" width="875px" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateBands="False" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyFields="ID"         
    DataMember="SqlDataSource9_DefaultView" StyleSetName="Windows7" 
    ID="wdgPrivileges"
    DataSourceID="WebHierarchicalDataSource7" Key="SqlDataSource9_DefaultView">
  <Columns>
     <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="ID" Key="ID" Hidden="true">
        <Header Text="ID" />
        <header text="ID" />
     </ig:BoundDataField>
     <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="Name" Key="Name" Width="95%">
        <Header Text="Name" />
        <header text="Name" />
    </ig:BoundDataField>                   
  </Columns>
</ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource13" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>" 
    SelectCommand="GetPrivilege" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommand="SetPrivilege" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="InsPrivilege" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">       
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />         
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />            
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />                     
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsPrivilege]
    @Name varchar(50)
AS
Begin
    INSERT INTO Privilege ([Name], LastUpdate)
    VALUES (@Name, GetDate())
end
```

I need the ID to be bound for the update SQL command.

Do I have to use it as a parameter in the insert also and just not use it?

**UPDATE**

```
<ig:WebHierarchicalDataSource ID="WebHierarchicalDataSource7" runat="server">
   <DataViews>
   <ig:DataView ID="SqlDataSource9_DefaultView" DataMember="DefaultView" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource13" />           
   </DataViews>       
</ig:WebHierarchicalDataSource>
```

**UPDATE**
This is the Update and Select stored procedure info...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource13" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>" 
        SelectCommand="GetPrivilege" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="SetPrivilege" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        InsertCommand="dmInsPrivilege" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">       
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />         
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />            
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />                     
        </InsertParameters>      
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Select Stored Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPrivilege]
AS
Begin   
    SELECT ID, [Name]
    FROM Privilege with (nolock)    
end
```

Update Stored Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetPrivilege]
    @ID int,
    @Name varchar(50)
AS
Begin
    UPDATE Privilege 
    SET [Name] = @Name, LastUpdate = GetDate()
    WHERE ID = @ID  
end
```

Error Message: 
[SqlException]: Procedure or function InsPrivilege has too many arguments specified.

Comment: Show us the full exception message, and show us the `UpdPrivileges` stored procedure.

Comment: I think you give us the code of `SqlDataSource13`, But your grid uses `WebHierarchicalDataSource7` ;).

Comment: The WebHierarchicalDataSource7 is defined with the DataSourceID of SqlDataSource13.  It is above.

Comment: Added the Update and Select stored procedures and error message.

Comment: I read that using asp:SqlDataSource requires all bound columns to be part of the commands.  Because my ID column is a bound column is it required that I use it in the Insert Command, even though I don't need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem...it is not SqlDataSource but the Infragistics Control that requires all bound fields in queries.
So, because my Id field is bound, I have to use it as a parameter in my insert command even though I don't need it; which is kind of weird.
But for anyone else with is problem...I solved it by adding the ID parameter in the insert statement and setting the default value to zero.